# No bootable device error after restoring debian image to annother ssd disk

Tags: linux, debian, uefi, dd, disk-image

I created an image of debian 7 on an SSD disk and later restored it on another computer with excatly same type of HW. however I'm getting the error message:

```
No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press key
```

The image was created using a live OS with the command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > backup.img.gz
```

And later restored to disk with:

```
gunzip -c backup.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda
```

I've done this before on older computers and it usually works fine. If i restore the image on the computer i created from it seems to be working.

These computers has EFI, could this be the issue? Any ideas, or workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, efi is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

On EFI systems the location of the bootloader is stored in motherboard non-volatile storage.
If you have a UEFI shell available you can use that to run the bootloader (typically locate in the EFI directory in root of the boot partition, alternatively either rename the bootloader to default name (bootx64.efi for x86-64) or boot from removeable media. Then you can reconfigure the grub-efi package which will reset the firmware configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to run `grub-install` in a chroot with your Debian system mounted there (including /boot/efi, /dev, /proc and /sys); the rescue image can be any live one booted in EFI mode (plug: [ALT Rescue](http://en.altlinux.org/rescue) should do).

[Rod's books](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) on the topic are highly recommended to understand what's going on.